# java efficient way to process big text files

Tags: java, file, optimization, bufferedreader

Im doing a frequency dictionary, in which i read 1000 files, each one with about 1000 lines. The approach i'm following is:

- BufferedReader to read fileByFile
- read the first file, get the first sentence, split the sentence to an array string, then fill in an hashmap with the values from the string array.
- do this for all the senteces in that file
- do this for all 1000 files

My problem is, this is not a very efficient way to do it, i'm taking about 4 minutes to do all this. I'v increased heap size, refactored the code to make sure i'm not doind something wrong. For this approach, i'm completly sure there's nothing i can improve in the code.

My bet is, each time a sentece is read, a split is applied, which, multiplied by 1000 sentences in a file and by 1000 files is a huge ammount of splits to process.
My idea is, instead of read and process file-by-file, i could read each file to a char array, and then make the split only once per file. That would ease the ammount of processing times consuming with the split. Any suggestions of implementation would be appreciated.

Comment: So, did you try what you suggested?

Comment: if you profile, you don't need to bet.

Comment: i don't really know how to do it :p that's why i need help. profile shows me 80% time with a char[] which i'm assuming is the reading sentence by sentece.

Comment: You may be sure there's nothing to improve in the existing code.  We're not.  Show your code.

Comment: ok i might have exagerated. What i mean is, the big ammount of considered time spent is in that huge amount of splits which i would like to reduce by folowing another approach. That's where i need help

Comment: How are you reading stuff ? bufferedReder.readLine() or something else ? Splitting a line by line is likely the same as splitting the entire file, you still have to do the same number of splits..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I have just implemented the POC of your dictionary. Fast and dirty. My files contained 868 lines each one but I created 1024 copies of the same file. (This is table of contents of Spring Framework documentation.)

I ran my test and it took 14020 ms (14 seconds!). BTW I ran it from eclipse that could decrease the speed a little bit.

So, I do not know where your problem is. Please try my code on your machine and if it runs faster try to compare it with your code and understand where the root problem.

Anyway my code is not the fastest I can write. 
I can create Pattern before loop and the use it instead of String.split(). String.split() calls Pattern.compile() every time. Creating pattern is very expensive.

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Map<String, Integer> words = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

    long before = System.currentTimeMillis();

    File dir = new File("c:/temp/files");
    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
        for (String line = reader.readLine();  line != null;  line = reader.readLine()) {
            String[] lineWords = line.split("\\s+");
            for (String word : lineWords) {
                int count = 1;
                Integer currentCount = words.get(word);
                if (currentCount != null) {
                    count = currentCount + 1;
                }
                words.put(word, count);
            }
        }
    }

    long after = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("run took " + (after - before) + " ms");
    System.out.println(words);
}
```

Comment: running on my laptop, your code, with pattern.split(sentence) instead of compiling pattern each time takes me 108204 ms.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about the the contents are in different files I would do the approach your are recommending.  Read all files and all lines into memory (string, or char array, whatever) and then do the 1 split and hash populate based on the one string/dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're doing, I don't think you want to use strings except when you access your map.

You want to:

loop through files
    read each file into a buffer of something like 1024
    process the buffer looking for word end characters
    create a String from the character array
    check your map
    if found, update your count, if not, create a new entry
    when you reach end of buffer, get the next buffer from the file
    at end, loop to next file

Split is probably pretty expensive since it has to interpret the expression each time.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the file as one big string and and then splitting that sounds like a good idea. String splitting/modifying can be surprisingly 'heavy' when it comes to garbage collection. Multiple lines/sentences means multiple Strings and with all the splits it means a huge amount of Strings (Strings are immutable, so any change to them will actually create a new String or multiple Strings)... this produces a lot of garbage to be collected, and the garbage collection could become a bottleneck (with a smaller heap, the maximum amount of memory is reached all the time, kicking off a garbage collection, which potentially needs to clean up hundreds of thousands or millions of separate String-objects).

Of course, without knowing your code this is just a wild guess, but back in the day, I got an old command line Java-programs' (it was a graph-algorithm producing a huge SVG-file) running time to drop from about 18 seconds to less than 0.5 seconds just by modifying the string-handling to use StringBuffers/Builders.

Another thing that springs to mind is using multiple threads (or a threadpool) to handle different files concurrently, and then combine the results at the end. Once you get the program to run "as fast as possible", the remaining bottleneck will be the disk access, and the only way (afaik) to get past that is faster disks (SSDs etc.).

Comment: that's exactly that way i think i should improve. But if i read the entire file to a char array, how can i apply the split ? That's what i need help for

Comment: Off the top off my head, read the file into a StringBuffer first, then call <yourBuffer>.toString().split(). Also, make sure the StringBuffer is sufficiently large (use the constructor that takes the initial capacity as an argument), so the buffer doesn't need to resize itself multiple times.

Comment: @user974594 Append each character to a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

One very simple approach which uses minimum heap space and should be (almost) as fast as anything else would be like

```
  int c;

  final String SEPARATORS = " \t,.\n"; // extend as needed

  final StringBuilder word = new StringBuilder();

  while( ( c = fileInputStream.read() ) >= 0 ) {
    final char letter = (char) c;

    if ( SEPARATORS.indexOf(letter) < 0 ) {

      word.append(letter);

    } else {

      processWord( word.toString() );
      word.setLength( 0 );

    }

  }
```

extend for more separator characters as needed, possibly use multi-threading to process multiple files concurrently until disc IO becomes the bottle neck...

Comment: Same thing here which I mentioned in my comment on my own answer: don't use the default constructor of StringBuffer/Builder, by default the Buffer/Builder can only hold 16 characters (refer to the JavaDoc of the class), and needs to resize itself multiple times as the files probably contain a lot of characters.

Comment: That's not a problem at all: When re-using the StringBuilder (as I did) it will only grow each time a word is encountered that is longer than all words before; this will stabilize quickly, so one can expect there won't be more than a handfull of resizings. This is as efficient as it gets.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using a bufferedReader, why do you need to read in a whole file explicitly?  I definitely wouldn't use split if you're after speed, remember, it has to evaluate a regular expression each time you run it.

Try something like this for your inner loop (note, I have not compiled this or tried to run it):

```
StringBuilder sb = null;
String delimiters = " .,\t"; //Build out all your word delimiters in a string here
for(int nextChar = br.read(); nextChar >= 0; nextChar = br.read()) {
    if(delimiters.indexOf(nextChar) < 0) {
        if(sb == null) sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append((char)(nextChar));
    } else {
        if(sb != null) {
            //Add sb.toString() to your map or increment it
            sb = null;
        }
    }
}
```

You could try using different sized buffers explicitly, but you probably won't get a performance improvement over this.